# precompiler conditional compiling two cases

Tags: ios, swift

I have something like this in my App:

```
#if PRODUCTION
let code: String? = "1111"
#elseif DEMO
let code: String? = "2222"
#elseif TEST
let code: String? = "3333"
#else
let code: String? = "0000"
#endif
```

The problem is that at a deployment target, which has the flags `DEMO` and `TEST`, I get `Definition conflicts with previous value` for the lines 4 and 6. How is this possible? isn't `#elseif` supposed to be exclusive?

**UPDATE**

Although it is strange, this works:

```
let code: String?

#if PRODUCTION
code = "1111"
#elseif DEMO
code = "2222"
#elseif TEST
code = "3333"
#else
code = "0000"
#endif
```

I also have targets where only `TEST` or `PRODUCTION` is defined and it worked with the previous code, so I suppose only cases that could possibly be compiled are parsed.

Comment: Both #elseif (DEMO and TEST) are valid in this case, but it must be only one.

Comment: @azimov note the ELSE which is pare of #elseif ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Build Configuration Statement*

> Each statement in the body of a build configuration statement is
>   parsed even if it’s not complied.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html

I don't know why Apple parses every statement in the Build Configuration Statement, but they do and I think this causes the problem.

Comment: I think it is not the complete truth, see my update, but close enough